# using pandas read.excel to read values in a single column

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to store my Watchlist column from excel sheet( check Image) into a variable and iterate over that in my code.

[image]

The sample of the code I wrote:

```
import pandas as pd
excel_file = 'file path.xlsx'

watchlist = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name = 'Input_Options', usecols = 'A')
print(watchlist)
```

but the output I am getting is as follows:

```
   Watchlist
0      NIFTY
1  BANKNIFTY
2    NIFTYIT
3        NaN
4        NaN
5        NaN
6        NaN
7        NaN
```

All I want is to remove these NaN rows as there are only few scripts in my Watchlist. How do I do that?? I might add new Scripts in my table later but for now I only want those 3 values stored in my `watchlist` variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
Lst=[]
for v in watchlist['Watchlist'].values:
    if v==v:
       Lst.append(v)
print (Lst)
```

Comment: well, after checking your reply, I managed to do this ```watchlist = watchlist.dropna()``` and got the result I wanted but now the real question is why is it showing those NaN values in the first place??

Comment: Your last row is 9 that's why.

Answer (score 0):

I used `watchlist = watchlist.dropna()` But still not sure why am I getting those NaN values in the 1st place.